# Would it be possible to alter an existing Oracle 12c database for supporting UTF-8 encoding without deleting it?

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, spring-boot, unicode

My `Spring Boot v1.3.5` `REST` Application with `JPA` & `hibernate` performs `CRUD` operation using `Oracle 12c`. I am facing an issue due to `Unicode Characters`. My existing `Oracle` database does not support `Unicode character` sets that's why they are displaying different from the originally they are.

So to resolve the issue I have created a new database with `AL32UTF8` character set using `DBCA` in `dev environment` but now we can't drop the existing database in `production` and can't create a new with `AL32UTF8` character set.

At relation database end:

I have column name "Path" which is of `NVARCHAR2` datatype which stores the full absolute path of a file.

In liqibase xml:

```
<createTable catalogName="xyz" tableName="file_details">
            <column name="id" type="NVARCHAR(36)">
                <constraints nullable="false"/>
            </column>
            <column name="path" type="NVARCHAR(255)"/>
        </createTable>
    </changeSet>
```

In object-relational mapping (Entity Class):

```
@Data
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
@Slf4j
@Entity
@Table(name = "FILE_DETAILS")
@EqualsAndHashCode(of = "id", callSuper = false)
public class FileDetails extends AbstractBaseEntity {
    @Id
    @Column(unique = true, length = 36)
    @NotNull
    private String id = UUID.randomUUID().toString();

    @Size(min = 1, max = 2000)
    @Column(name = "path")
    @NotNull
    @NotBlank
    private String path;
}
```

**Would it be possible to alter an existing database for supporting `UTF-8` encoding without deleting it?**

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/NLSPG/ch11charsetmig.htm#NLSPG979

Comment: What is your current character set? Having Non-Unicode for `NVARCHAR` (i.e. `NLS_NCHAR_CHARACTERSET`) would be **very** special.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit `WE8MSWIN1252: Microsoft Windows West European Code Page 1252`

Comment: Are you sure? According [Choosing a National Character Set](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/NLSPG/ch2charset.htm#NLSPG180) it can be only `UTF8` or `AL16UTF16`

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit If those were UTF8 or UTF16 then I would not get this issue.

Comment: Well, perhaps you just set your client character set wrong, see https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/java.112/e16548/global.htm#JJDBC28644

Comment: Please edit your question instead of putting such ugly comments and try `SELECT * FROM NLS_Database_PARAMETERS where parameter like '%CHARACTERSET';` instead of SESSION parameters.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit I have created database using dbca so there is no option for specifying `NATIONAL CHARACTER SET`. It has only option to choose `CHARACTER SET` encoding.

Comment: Then it is even more likely that your `NLS_NCHAR_CHARACTERSET` is **not** `WE8MSWIN1252`

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit yes

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147782/discussion-between-wernfried-domscheit-and-ashish-pancholi).